# Calculate range represented by missing data - R

Tags: r

I have a dataset with values representing positions (this is SNPs/genomics work) in columns.

I am trying to figure out a way to calculate the distance of each stretch of missing data (the "gaps" - shown below as NA). E.g. 1466-1650 = 184

Would also like to calculate the stretch of the continuous observations, but guess that would be relatively easy once I've figured out the first issue. E.g. 1450-1466 = 16

Here's an example on how the data is organised:

```
1450
1466
NA
NA
1650
1654
1943
NA
2568
```

This question ties in with my next issue trying to analyse all the samples in the data set - looping through each sample - please [see my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46770761/for-loop-dataframe-for-each-column-combine-output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the `rle` function (run-length encoding).  Something like this...

```
vec <- c(1450,1466,NA,NA,1650,1654,1943,NA,2568) #your data

rl <- rle(is.na(vec)) #rle on whether values are NA
```

this produces

```
rl
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:5] 2 2 3 1 1
  values : logi [1:5] FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

so then you can work out the gap lengths like this

```
gaps <- vec[cumsum(rl$lengths)[rl$values]+1] - #upper bound of each NA group
        vec[c(1,cumsum(rl$lengths))[rl$values]] #lower bound

gaps
[1] 184 625
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to make another column with the continuous, using: rl2 <- rle(!is.na(df$data)) #rle on whether values are NOT NA - but I can't get the cumsum working, any suggestions?

Comment: Figured it out, in case anyone need this (PS single observations are reported as NA):                                               
    cont <- df$data[cumsum(r2$lengths)[r2$values]]- #upper_bound 
           df$data[cumsum(r2$lengths)[r2$values]-1] #lower_bound

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully something like this will help:

Select the non empty rows, then find the difference between them, then attach them to the data excluding the first index.

```
nonEmptyRows<-which(!is.na(df$data))
df[nonEmptyRows[-1], "gaps"]<-diff(df$data[nonEmptyRows])

 data gaps
 1450   NA
 1466   16
   NA   NA
   NA   NA
 1650  184
 1654    4
 1943  289
   NA   NA
 2568  625
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to extract the gap length (i.e. the first value after the NAs - e.g. 184) and the continuous length (4+289) into separate columns?