# For loop dataframe for each column combine output

Tags: r

Apologies in advance if this is considered a question I should be able to answer from other inquiries.

I got a data frame with multiple columns - like this:

```
v1<-c(1450,NA, NA, 1466,NA,NA,1650,1654,1943,NA,2568,NA, 7586)
v2<-c(1450,NA, NA, 1466,1561,NA,1650,NA,NA,NA,2568,NA, 7586)
df<-data.frame(v1, v2)
```

I want to do the following for each column:

```
r1_v1 <- rle(is.na(df$v1)) #rle on whether values are NA
r2_v1 <- rle(!is.na(df$v1)) #rle on whether values are NOT NA
gaps_v1 <- df$v1[cumsum(r1_v1$lengths)[r1_v1$values]+1] - #upper bound of each NA group
        df$v1[c(1,cumsum(r1_v1$lengths))[r1_v1$values]] #lower bound
write.table(gaps_v1, file="gaps_v1.txt", sep=",")
x<- df$v1[cumsum(r2_v1$lengths)[r2_v1$values]]
x2 <- x[-1]
cont_v1<- x2-
        df$v1[cumsum(r1_v1$lengths)[r1_v1$values]+1]
cont_v1<-replace(cont_v1, cont_v1==0, 1)
write.table(cont_v1, file="cont_v1.txt", sep=",")
```

I've tried using *for* loops - but cannot figure out how to loop through each column (v1, v2, etc).

Like shown above I would like the *gaps* and the *cont* output for each column written as a file.

Alternatively they could be compiled into 1 data frame / list with the respective column names as additional variables, like this:

```
"x", "column"
"1",16, "v1"
"2",184, "v1"
"3",625, "v1"
"4",5018, "v1"
"5", 16, "v2"
"6", 89, "v2"
...
```

EDIT: in words: I would like to run the *rle* to calculate the length of the gaps between the numbers (i.e. from 1450-1466 in v1), and the length of continuous observations (i.e. 1466-1561 in v2) for each column (v1, v2, etc) in the data set. I already had some help with the *rle* calculation, now I am asking for help setting up a loop to analyse my entire data set.

EDIT2: it may be better to build everything up from scratch, please also see my other post describing the initial problem (not the loop). [Link to previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46684038/calculate-range-represented-by-missing-data-r)

Comment: You should explain in words what you want to do

Comment: You can calculate for each column using `apply()` like this: `apply(df, 2, function(x) rle(!is.na(x)))`, is that what you're going for?

Comment: Thanks! I struggle a bit with importing the `rle` data into the _gaps_ (`cumsum`). I get `rle` like this: `r1<-lapply(df, function(x) rle(is.na(x)))` and I've been trying to get the r1$v1 inserted into this `apply` function with no luck: `gaps<-lapply(df, function(x) x[cumsum(r1$x$lengths)` `[r1$x$values]+1]-x[c(1,cumsum(r1$x$lengths))[r1$x$values]] )`
What am I missing?